# Issue with background image when outputting to emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap, background

Image below shows the output of my game. However as can be seen the background image only takes up half of the screen. Code used for the canvas.drawbitmap also provided, which I believe is to be changed when scaling the image. Any help would be appreciated.

canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);

[Output image of background in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dukay.png)

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was simply change the background image. Did this through a PNG image found online. Looked at the dimensions the image was, found an image already with greater dimensions which took the entire background image.